# Difference between _%_% and __% in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am learning basics of SQL through [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) and during understanding basics of [wildcards](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) I went through the following query:

```
--Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%'
```

as per the example following query will search the table where `CustomerName` column start with 'a' and have at least 3 characters in length.

However, I try the following query also:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a__%'
```

The above query also gives me the exact same result.
I want to know whether there is any difference in both queries? Does the second query produce a different output in some specific scenario? If yes what will be that scenario?

Comment: I think both is same

Comment: @YogeshSharma but we have placed % in the end that means it will print any no of character in the end. Also i have executed both queries, both are showing same output.

Comment: Actually looks like a mistake.

Comment: The author of the code may have felt that a double underscore could easily be misread as a single underscore. The first pattern makes it absolutely clear, in an odd sort of way, that there are two underscores present. The patterns are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both start with `A`, and end with `%`. In the middle part, the first says "*one char, then between zero and many chars, then one char*", while the second one says "*one char, then one char*".

Considering that the part that comes after them (*the final part*) is `%`, which means "*between zero and many chars*", I can only see both clauses as identical, as they both essentially just want a string starting with `A` then at least two following characters. Perhaps if there were at least some limitations on what characters were allowed by the `_`, then maybe they could have been different.

If I had to choose, I'd go with the second one for being more intuitive. After all, many other masks (*e.g. `a%%%%%%_%%_%%%%%`*) will yield the same effect, but why the weird complexity?

Comment: Agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

For Like operator a single underscore "_" means, any single character, so if you put One underscore like

`ColumnName LIKE 'a_%'`

you basically saying you need a string where first letter is 'a' then followed by another single character and then followed by anything or nothing.

`ColumnName LIKE 'a__%'` OR `ColumnName LIKE 'a_%_%'`

Both expressions mean first letter 'a' then followed by two characters and then followed by anything or nothing.  Or in simple English any string with 3 or more character starting with `a`.